# How to resolve "MismatchingStateError: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning!" when using Github Authentication in a Flask App?

Tags: python, flask, github-api, flask-login, flask-dance

I am using the Flask-Dance package for logging in to my app via Github and I've configured it in my project but I get this error in response:

```
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MismatchingStateError: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning!      State not equal in request and response.
```

What can I do ?

My code is:

```py
github_bp = make_github_blueprint()
app.register_blueprint(github_bp, url_prefix="/login")
```

and

```py
@app.route('/')
def github():
    if not github.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for('github.login'))
    resp = github.get('/user')
    assert resp.ok
    login = resp.json()['login']
    return f'You are {login} on GitHub'
```